# Change dicom Transfer Syntax showing no registered codec using mDCM

Tags: c#, dicom, image-compression

I am having issue while changing the Transfer Syntax.
I am using `mDCM` library and I have added the Dicom.Codec.dll to the project as well.
The compressed files are having `0002,0010,Transfer Syntax UID=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.90` (JPEG 2000 Image Compression (Lossless Only)).
Error: DicomCodecException was caught. No registered codec for transfer syntax!

My code:

```
string file = "C:\\Dicom\\1001.dcm";
string output = "C:\\Dicom\\Decompressed\\1001.dcm";
DicomFileFormat ff = new DicomFileFormat();
ff.Load(file, Dicom.DicomReadOptions.Default);
ff.ChangeTransferSytnax(DicomTransferSyntax.ExplicitVRLittleEndian, null); // Error here. No registered codec for transfer syntax!.
Dicom.Imaging.DicomImage im = new Dicom.Imaging.DicomImage(ff.Dataset);
System.Drawing.Image i = im.Render();
i.Save(output);
```

Another thing that I noted is that the tag `7FE0,0010,Pixel Data=0`. For other dicom files, `Pixel data` tag is having values greater than `0`.

The file is not opening in my other dicom viewers (ezDICOM, DicomWorks, IrfanView etc.) as well. So, I thought the file is corrupted. But, then the client gave us an `application(.exe)` which decompresses the file.
After decompression, all my viewers was showing the image properly.
Decompressed files was having `7FE0,0010,Pixel Data=131072`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error mentioned, I was not registering the codec.

This line registered the codec.

```
Dicom.Codec.Jpeg2000.DcmJpeg2000Codec.Register();
```